# Rational function between a constant and a third root

Tags: inequality, polynomials

Is there a rational function $f(x)\in{\mathbb Q}(x)$ such that
$\sqrt{2} \leq f(x) \leq \sqrt[3]{2x}$ for all $x\geq\sqrt{2}$ ?

My thoughts : it is easy to find such an $f$ if we relax 
the conditions to $f(x)\in{\mathbb R}(x)$ (take $f$ constant
equal to $\sqrt{2}$), however no easy perturbation of this
solution seems to solve the original problem. Clearly $f$
must have zero degree in $x$ and can be written in the form 
$x+(x^2-2)g(x)$ where $g$ is another rational function. Then I am stuck.

Comment: I don't think this is true but if $f=\frac{P}{Q}$, where the degree of $P$ is less than $Q$, then the absolute value of $f$ would eventually decrease would it not? and if the degree of $P$ is larger than $Q$, then $\frac{P}{Q\sqrt[3]{2x}}$ would be eventually increasing, would it not?

Comment: @MXYMXY Clearly the degree of $P$ must equal the degree of $Q$. Otherwise $f$ would either grow too fast for the upper bound or decrease too fast for the lower bound

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest function I can find seems $f(x) = \dfrac{2x+2}{x+2}$.  It is easily verified this satisfies the double inequality for $x \ge \sqrt2$.

This was obtained by looking at linear approximants, and then setting the conditions $f(\sqrt2) = \sqrt2, f(x) \ge \sqrt2$ and finally the RHS inequality.

Even among linear functions, there are of course many choices, many of which can be got from the form $f(x) = \dfrac{ax+2b}{bx+a}$, with $(a, b) \in \{ (3,2), (5, 2), (5, 3), (7, 3), (7, 4), ... \}$

...which leads to the thought $\dfrac{(2n\pm1)x+2n}{nx + 2n\pm1}$ could work for $1< n \in \mathbb N$  (not checked).